# Created a role in postgres database and no way to delete db or connect

Tags: database, postgresql, terminal, homebrew, psql

I installed postgresql on homebrew and I am unable to connect to db by running psql. The error I get is psql: FATAL:  role "some-role-name" does not exist. This is not a newly installed postgres and I believe I created a db on template1. Now I have no way of access db (creating a new db or deleting existing db with this role). If I try to add the role, I can't because the role does not exist.

I tried uninstalling via homebrew but still getting the same error. This is a common issue for many people but it seems like most of the answers is just creating the missing role (i.e. createuser postgresql). I am not missing the role postgresql but rather some other role I probably created before. Also I can not create the role I am missing because the role does not exist.

I deleted every single postgresql file/folder, uninstalled and reinstalled via brew and I still get this error with the exact same missing role.

Comment: If this database does not contain something you need, you should probably remove everything and start from scratch. `brew uninstall postgresql` followed by `rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres`. Failing that, IIRC, brew installation creates a default postgres database which should be accessible by `psql -d postgres`

Comment: That still doesn't work.  When I reinstall postgresql, it still showing the same error with the same missing role.  Where is this data stored?

Comment: Are you removing the postgresql files in /usr/local/var/postgres? Because after that's removed there's nothing left in the system for pg to accidentally include. If you are still getting that error then either not everything is removed/you have a custom conf/the role indeed does not exist. If #3, then you can issue `psql -d postgres` and get into the database.

Also check pg_hba.conf for if the specific interface you are using permits access to the database.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the **exact** command you run. Can you connect using the superuser? e.g. `psql -U postgres -d postgres`? If yes, then please [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56105952/edit) the output of the `\dg` command to your question.